# Get device owner from Azure Active Directory group members

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there a simple way to get the owners of all devices that are assigned to a particular group? I have a Azure AD group that has devices assigned to it and I would like to change all of the assignments from device to user. Is there a way I can find out the owner of the device and assign them as a member in bulk?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below Powershell Script to get the the device owners of the devices present in the group.

```
Connect-AzureAD
$Result=@()
$Members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "b446d49b-****-****-****-************"
foreach ($Member in $Members) {
    $DeviceOwner = $Member|Get-AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner
    $deviceprops = [ordered] @{
        DeviceDisplayName = $Member.DisplayName
        DeviceObjectID = $Member.ObjectId
        OwnerDisplayName = $DeviceOwner.DisplayName
        OwnerUserPrincipalName = $DeviceOwner.UserPrincipalName
        OwnerObjectID = $DeviceOwner.ObjectId 
    }
    $deviceobj = new-object -Type PSObject -Property $deviceprops
    $Result += $deviceobj
}
$Result 
$Result | Export-CSV "C:\DeviceOwners.csv"
```

I have tested the above on my environment I have only devices present in a group.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Then to Add owners to the group you can import the csv and add the owners to the Group and then similarly remove the Devices from Group. I tested it only for GetADUser as I don’t want to do the changes in my AAD group.

**Code:**

```
$Owners = Import-Csv -Path "C:\DeviceOwners.csv"
#$Owners|Format-Table
Connect-AzureAD
$Owners | ForEach-Object {
#$Owner = $_
#Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $Owner.OwnerObjectID
$Owner = $_
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "b446d49b-****-****-****-************" -RefObjectId $Owner.OwnerObjectID
#$Owner = $_
#Remove-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "b446d49b-****-****-****-************" -MemberId $Owner.DeviceObjectID
}
```

**Note :**
First Add the Owners to the Group . While running the above script to add Owners to Group keep the `Remove` command commented . After you have added the Owners to the Group then you can comment the `Add` command and use the `Remove` command to remove the Devices from the Group.

[image]

**Reference:**

Install Powersell azuread module :
**Command:** `Install-Module -Name AzureAD`

[AzureAD Group Module | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0#groups)